# What is ST_Geometry, ST_Curve and ST_Surface on PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, st-geometry, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

I dont't have any experience with geographics databases so I hope that you be patiente with me, so I opened this question ([PostGis and datatypes WKT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227603/postgis-and-datatypes-wkt/227608#227608)) in the past week about the datatypes in the postgis, but later I continued to read the documentation and then I found the following.

- ST_Curve = http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_Length.html
- ST_Geometry = http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_GeomFromEWKB.html
- ST_Surface = http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_Area.html

What are these datatypes? they are instanciable? and why they aren't here https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/liblwgeom/liblwgeom.h.in#L82 (that link is the link that was used to answer my question that I mencioned on the begining of the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ST_Geometry` type](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbspatial/pg-api-spatial-st-geometry-type.html) is the maximal supertype of the geometry type hierarchy, `ST_Curve` and `ST_Surface` are direct subtypes.

The types you list are further down the line (more specialized). You can create `ST_Geometry`, `ST_Surface` and `ST_Curve` objects directly, as is shown in the [ArcGIS documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-geometry.htm).